# SQL Query of 2 Tables forming a category tree

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have 2 Tables. The first one is the Categorie's IDs.

Category

| CategoryID | ParentID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 5 |

Category Name

| CategoryID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Top |
| 2 | Cat1 |
| 3 | Cat2 |
| 4 | Cat3 |
| 5 | Another1 |
| 6 | RandCat |

Need to produce a query that will return the Category Tree.

| CategoryID | Cat Name | Parent Cat Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Top |  |
| 2 | Cat1 | Top |
| 3 | Cat2 | Top |
| 4 | Cat3 | Cat1 |
| 5 | Another1 | Cat2 |
| 6 | RandCat | Another1 |

We can have up to 3 layers of SubCategories and would have to grow the table as required.

Thanks For any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need left join with base table as `category_name`.

```
Select cn.categoryid, cn.cat_name,
       Cnp.cat_name as parent_category
  From category_name cn
  Left join category c on c.categoryid = cn.categoryid
  Left join category_name cnp on cnp.categoryid = c.parentid;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like `JOIN`s:

```
select c.categoryid, cn.name, cnp.name
from category c left join
     categoryname cn
     on cn.categoryid = c.categoryid left join
     categoryname cnp
     on cnp.categoryid = c.parentid;
```